# Computing sums in some CSV files horizontally and in other CSV files vertically

Tags: python, csv

I'd like to eliminate the code duplication in the following two methods by moving the common code into a separate method callable by both. The comments indicate the blocks of code that have a differing implementation in each method.

```
def compute_totals_h(self, size, bad_codes):
    with open(self._in_file_path, self._FILE_READ_MODE) as f:
        # initialize reader
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        field_names = reader.next()
        for i, code in enumerate(field_names):
            code = code.strip(string.punctuation).upper()
            field_names[i] = code       
        for code in field_names:
            if (len(code) <= size) and (code not in bad_codes):
                self._totals[code] = 0

        for row in reader:
            # get totals
            for i, val in enumerate(row):
                code = field_names[i]
                if (code in self._totals):
                    self._totals[code] += string_utils.to_int(val)

    self._write_totals()

def compute_totals_v(self, code_field, est_field):
    with open(self._in_file_path, self._FILE_READ_MODE) as f:
        # initialize reader
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)

        for row in reader:
            # get totals
            code = row[code_field].strip(string.punctuation).upper()
            est = string_utils.to_int(row[est_field])
            if code in self._totals:
                self._totals[code] += est
            else:
                self._totals[code] = est

    self._write_totals()
```

I'm thinking of a solution that has a common abstract method that can be called from `compute_totals_h` and `compute_totals_v` with each method passing functions to handle its implementation. I can't figure out how to do this while passing the arguments for each implementation correctly. It would look something like:

```
def compute_totals(self, initialize_reader, get_totals):
    with open(self._in_file_path, self._FILE_READ_MODE) as f:
        reader = initialize_reader(f)

        for row in reader:
            get_totals(row)

        self._write_totals()
```

I'll also appreciate suggestions on a better way of handling this type of code refactoring to eliminate this general class of code duplication problems.

Comment: `string_utils.to_int`? Any reason to not use the builtin `int`?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! So that we may provide you with better advice, could you tell us more about the task you are trying to accomplish? What class does this code appear in? Why do you have a length limit on field names? What is `code_field` and `est_field`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I'm not using `int` since I need to handle strings that are not numeric in a predictable way (returning `0`). `string_utils.to_int` is a wrapper function around `int` which catches `ValueError` and `TypeError` exceptions.

Comment: @200_success your edits actually capture the nature of the task. One set of CSV files has codes spread across columns another has codes appearing in rows within one column. The two methods handle the two formats. I'd like to merge their common parts. Does this help?

Comment: It does help to know that there are multiple sets of files involved.

Comment: Any suggestions on the elimination of duplication? That is the core issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Where we improve the existing code

First of, let's start by talking a bit about some issues in your code. We'll see if we can factorize some bits latter.

The first thing to note is that you iterate twice over your `field_names` to construct its final form and initialize `self._totals`. There is no need for it:

```
field_names = reader.next()
for i, code in enumerate(field_names):
    code = code.strip(string.punctuation).upper()
    field_names[i] = code
    if (len(code) <= size) and (code not in bad_codes):
        self._totals[code] = 0
```

Next, we see that you differentiate the behaviours of your sums whether `self._totals[code]` has been initalized or not. One way to simplify it is to turn it into a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). To be more precise, you will have to define `self._totals = defaultdict(int)` instead of `self._totals = dict()`. This will allow you to write, in `compute_totals_v`:

```
for row in reader:
    # get totals
    code = row[code_field].strip(string.punctuation).upper()
    self._totals[code] += string_utils.to_int(row[est_field])
```

This will also allow you to write, in `compute_totals_h`:

```
for row in reader:
    # get totals
    for code, val in zip(field_names, row):
        if (len(code) <= size) and (code not in bad_codes):
            self._totals[code] += string_utils.to_int(val)
```

eliminating the need to initialize `self._totals` fields. Also, using `zip` here is more idiomatic. And since you are using Python 2 (I guess `reader.next()` would have been `next(reader)` in Python 3) you can use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to avoid building a new list in memory.

We can see here that we're moving the test that initialized `self._totals[code]` into the “get totals” loop. But it is not efficient since we are re-doing it for each row of data. Time to improve that filtering by getting something closer to the `if code in self._totals` we had. The easiest way is to turn invalid codes into `None` and check `if code is not None` instead:

```
def compute_totals_h(self, size, bad_codes):
    with open(self._in_file_path, self._FILE_READ_MODE) as f:
        # initialize reader
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        field_names = [c if (len(c) <= size) and (c not in bad_code)
                       else None
                       for c in (
                           code.strip(string.punctuation).upper()
                           for code in reader.next())]

        for row in reader:
            # get totals
            for code, val in zip(field_names, row):
                if code is not None:
                    self._totals[code] += string_utils.to_int(val)

    self._write_totals()
```

We now have something closer to `compute_totals_v` and can start to work on factorizing.

## Where we get to do what you ask for

The general layout you extracted for your `compute_totals` method is quite close to what `compute_totals_v` and `compute_totals_h` has become. You should note, however, that `compute_totals_h` needs to return both `reader` and `field_names` for its initialization. So we need to return a dummy value (let's say `None`) in the initialization function for `compute_totals_v` as well. And thus, we need to accept a second parameter (the dummy value or `field_names`) in `get_totals` for both methods.

We also need to define the helper functions as inner functions of the method so we can capture the parameters of the method once and for all without having to pass them around.

```
# Somewhere, where you define self._totals:
# self._totals = defaultdict(int)

def compute_totals_h(self, size, bad_codes):
    def _init_reader(file_handler):
        reader = csv.reader(file_handler)
        field_names = [c if (len(c) <= size) and (c not in bad_code)
                       else None
                       for c in (
                           code.strip(string.punctuation).upper()
                           for code in reader.next())]
        return reader, field_names

    def _get_totals(row, field_names):
        for code, val in zip(field_names, row):
            if code is not None:
                self._totals[code] += string_utils.to_int(val)

    self.compute_totals(_init_reader, _get_totals)


def compute_totals_v(self, code_field, est_field):
    def _get_totals(row, *args):
        code = row[code_field].strip(string.punctuation).upper()
        self._totals[code] += string_utils.to_int(row[est_field])

    self.compute_totals(lambda f: (csv.DictReader(f), None), _get_totals)

def compute_totals(self, initialize_reader, get_totals):
    with open(self._in_file_path, self._FILE_READ_MODE) as f:
        reader, field_names = initialize_reader(f)

        for row in reader:
            get_totals(row, field_names)

    self._write_totals()
```

I'm not convinced, however, of the improvement of this change. Readability seems worse to me. And calling the `get_totals` function for each row has its slight overhead.

Comment: This answer is brilliant and exactly what I was looking for! Also, thanks for the code improvements. I agree on the decreased readability but it seems a like a good and extensible solution to this general class of factoring problems. It also seems more concise than using abstract base classes.